# Trying to write a bash wrapper script around curl to get and update a google spreadsheet

Tags: linux, curl, get, command-line-interface, spreadsheet

I looked at similar 'curl/update Google spreadsheet' questions, but didn't exactly find the answer that I was looking for...

I followed the Google API documentation and created a project, added google drive API (to access spreadsheets), created the necessary credentials, added a service account with edit access, it generated a json file, and it created the following details:

```
"{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "projectblah",
  "private_key_id": "34234daf....",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----------END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "test@projectblah.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "2342434234",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url":     

"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/test@projectblah.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}"
```

Now from the linux cli I am trying to print/get all rows from my spreadsheet using the above credentials, also need to add/append rows to it... I can see that this can be accomplished by php, java, python etc... but my client prefers that I use bash and keep it simple...

What are the flags and params I need to pass/use for curl to GET and POST?

Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked through this? https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing

Comment: yeah I did, but didn't help much from what I want to achieve, I tried several curl methods but didn't get anywhere with it....

Comment: Thank you Mike. I was able to get this working from a browser by going through this link: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get and 'Try this API', here you can expand the window and see the actual 'curl' syntax, but unable to get it working from the command line: curl \
  'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[SPREADSHEETID]/values/[RANGE]?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed

Comment: curl -X GET 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files' --header 'Authorization: Bearer ya29......'   --header 'Accept: application/json'   --compressed
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
 }
}
Generated the token by running: oauth2l fetch --credentials=secret-1.json --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

Comment: curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer 33sadfafaccesstoken' https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/sheetidfromthebrowserurl/B3:F19 - this worked